# Change view with Segment View Control

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I have created a view in my View controller which has **UISegmentControl** and a **UIScrollView**

```
let segmentControl : UISegmentedControl = {
    let segmentItems = ["Personal","Statistics","Calendar"]
    let segmentControl = UISegmentedControl(items: segmentItems)
    segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    segmentControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectIn(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    segmentControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return segmentControl
}()

let subView : UIScrollView = {
    let view = UIScrollView()
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()
```

In viewDidLoad I added

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true

    view.addSubview(segmentControl)
    view.addSubview(subView)
    setLayout()
}
```

and added layout as follows

```
func setLayout(){
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        segmentControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10),
        segmentControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        segmentControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
        segmentControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),

        subView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentControl.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
        subView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        subView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
        subView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
    ])
}
```

and tried to add **PersonalView (UIView)** when any segmentControl is pressed

```
@objc func selectIn(sender: UISegmentedControl){
        subView.addSubview(pvc)
}
```

My personalView is as follows

```
class PersonalView: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let tempValueForTable : Int = 10

let todayLabel : UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Today"
    label.font = .montserratSemiBold
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.backgroundColor = .green
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(todayLabel)
    setLayout()

}

private func setLayout(){
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        todayLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
        todayLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        todayLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
        todayLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25),
    ])
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}}
```

Still I am not able to get view and in further update I need to add more view in same **ScrollView**

Comment: Did you forget to add the constraints on the pvc regarding its superview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.when you are using auto layout constraints you must set this false after add.

```
SomeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

2.After you add your subView you must set its constraints and call **view.layoutIfNeeded()**

```
subView.addSubview(pvc)
pvc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
     pvc.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subView.trailingAnchor),
     pvc.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subView.leadingAnchor),
     pvc.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subView.topAnchor),
     pvc.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subView.bottomAnchor),
])
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked
Still I need to add
`pvc.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subView.widthAnchor)` so that I can get same width as needed